# How to link a parent model to a deeply nested one on creation/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

First off, I've tried looking around but I can't seem to find a definitive answer as to if and how to this if it is possible.

Consider these models

```rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :users, through: :profiles

  validates :name, :owner, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :groups, through: :profiles
  has_many :owned_groups, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :owner_id, optional: true

  validates :name, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles
end
```

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  enum role: [:admin, :moderator, :user]

  validates :user, :group, :role, presence: true
end
```

Is there any way shape or form where I can have a deeply nested form to create all this so the following can happen ? Or will it truly be necessary to manually create the profile **after** the group/admin are created ?

```rb
deeply_nested_params = params.require(:group).permit(
  :name,
  owner_attributes: [
    :id, # nil on create
    :name,
    profiles_attributes: [
      :id, # nil on create
      :role
    ]
  ]
)
group = Group.new(deeply_nested_params) #=> #<Group>
group.owner.profiles.first.group == group #=> true
# last but not least
group.valid? #=> true
```

I'm mainly asking out of curiosity and also because I would find it more "elegant" in a way to truly create a `group` (in my example) in one line.

PS: the issue with the current way I'm trying things is that `group.owner.profiles.first.group` is nil so the validations fail

PS2: I do have a 3 line (if you use `{}` blocks instead) 1 save solution (sort of) that works. But again, I'm curious about a solution where this workaround be required.

```rb
group = Group.new(deeply_nested_params) #=> #<Group>
group.owner.profiles.select do |profile| # select because nothing is saved yet so find won't work
  profile.id.nil? # new records only
end.each do |profile|
  profile.group = group
end
group.save!
```

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_for only works well for one-to-one, and one-to-many associations, but you group-user association is many-to-many

Comment: Logically, you can't save the record in the profiles table without knowing the user and group ids, so both User and Group have to be saved before Profile can be created.

Comment: I'd like to see the user interface design for creating a User, Group and Profile, all together, simultaneously, in a single step..

Comment: @DavidAldridge not necessarily, I've added an edit that show you can "technically" do this in a single `save` but you need to manipulate the unsaved models between the `new` and the `save`. This of course means it cannot be shortened to a single `create!` for example (which is kind of the purpose of the question)

Comment: Your models and the rest of the question don't make sense together. The is no explaination where this `group.admin` method is coming from. Nor is there an explaination of what the desired output should be.

Comment: I tried to make an abstract structure for my post so I could remove all the complexities of my existing real life models. concept is basically you can "own" multiple groups, you can also be a member of multiple groups thanks to your profiles. On signup you might want to create a group at the same time as your user (and thus your profile since you might as well be a member of your group for anything to make sense)